# Not able to send email via PHP using office 365 smtp. Works on localhost but fails online

Tags: php, email

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
        $email =  $_POST["email"];
        $phone =  $_POST["phone"];
        $message = $_POST["message"];

        $mailbody="";
        $mailbody.="Hello,<br/><br/>You have a new contact on your website:<br/><br/>";
        $mailbody.="Name: ".$name."<br />\r\n"; 
        $mailbody.="Email: ".$email."<br />\r\n";
        $mailbody.="Phone: ".$phone."<br />\r\n";
        $mailbody.="Message: ".$message."<br />\r\n";

        require_once('./bat/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
        $mail = new PHPMailer();

        $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP

        // SMTP Configuration
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;            // enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';        
        $mail->Host = "smtp.office365.com";  // SMTP server
        $mail->Username = "email@domain.com";
        $mail->Password = "****"; 

        $mail->Port = 587; // optional if you don't want to use the default 

        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->From = "email@domain.com";
        $mail->FromName = "Website Name";
        $mail->Subject = "Subject";
        $mail->AltBody = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test
        $mail->MsgHTML($mailbody);

        // Add as many as you want
        $mail->AddAddress("email@domain.com", "Name");

        if(!$mail->Send()) {
              //header("Location:contact.php?sent=0#sent");
              echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        } else {
             header("Location:contact.php?sent=1#sent");
        }
```

> When I test on localhost the email sends successfully and gets delivered.
>   When I test online it throws the following error: Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
>
> I tried to remove $mail->IsSMTP(); as mentioned in one of the suggestions. The scripts runs online and returns true but the email never gets delivered.

Comment: Show us more details about error by ```$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;```

Comment: @TomaszWinter 
2016-12-05 08:56:12
SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection timed out (110) 2016-12-05 08:56:12
SMTP connect() failed. Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.